# Xpath - obtener solo valores

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract some data with seleneitor, and I have doubts when I extract the text to transform it into DF. I show an example:

```
texto_columnas = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div/section[4]/section/div[1]/ul')

texto_columnas = texto_columnas.text

print(texto_columnas)
```

if i run i get this result:

Today
15
Temperature
22°
Wind
16
km/h
Tomorrow
16
Temperature
20°
Wind
13
km/h

I want to remove all texts except the Today and Tomorrow fields.

How could I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can slice and get the values or remove the itens what you want.

```
today = texto_columnas[0:7] # or texto_columnas[6:7] if you want only the field
tomorrow= texto_columnas[36:48] # or texto_columnas[47:48] if you want only the field
```

If you want all in the same text, you can concatenate:

```
today_and_tomorrrow = today+tomorrow
```

You can read all this informations in Python documentation too.